# Django - How to filter dropdown selection list as ForeignKey

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

In Django, how can I filter a dropdown selection list as a ForeignKey? This should only be for those patients who are assigned to a doctor, because in my `Appointment` model I already select a doctor.

Now after selecting a doctor, I want to show only the patients with `ForeignKey` of that doctor, not all patients.

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, null=True, blank=True ,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)`
```

```
class Appointments(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(USER, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, null=True, blank=True ,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patients, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)`
```

Answer (score 2):

May be something like this

```
patient_list = Patient.objects.filter(doctor__id=id_getting_from_drop_down)
```